# Inserting a lot of markers in an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a static analysis plugin for Eclipse. I have some problems with markers. When I insert around 2500 or 4000 markers (customized but not very big), it takes almost 2 minutes to insert all of them.

My plugin does nothing else but add these markers – there is no document cleaning nor markers cleaning – so I'm surprised at the low performance. However, I see some other tools such as [Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) that seems to go very fast inserting markers. What could cause my plugin to be so slow when inserting markers?

Comment: Possibly they are just using `WorkspaceJob` or `WorkspaceModifyOperation` to reduce the number of resource change events generated.

Comment: I improved the language and readability a bit, and added a link to the Checkstyle plugin. Perhaps you could add a bit of code to show how you are going about inserting the markers?

Comment: Oh my god greg-449 you just solved hours of labours for me :o Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!